# Is there a way that I can cast the variables in my Java program so that I get a double output?

Tags: java, casting, average

I am a beginner in Java and I am being asked to write a program to find the average of three grades. I am trying to figure out how to get a double output by type casting but I don't know where to cast. I have already written some code myself but the grader is still saying I'm not getting the right answer.

Here are the program instructions:

> In the code below, type in three made up int grades and then sum and
> average them. Use casting to report the result as a double. For
> example, if the grades are 90, 100, and 94, the sum of the three
> numbers is 90 + 100 + 94 = 284, and the average is the sum 284 divided
> by 3 which casted to a double is 94.666667. You should use your
> variables instead of the numbers in your formulas. Follow the
> pseudocode below.
>
> Type in three made up int grades and then sum and average them. Use
> type casting to report the result as a double.

Here is my code:

```
public class Challenge1_6
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // 1. Declare 3 int variables called grade1, grade2, grade3
      // and initialize them to 3 values
       int grade1 = 78;
       int grade2 = 95;
       int grade3 = 84;

      // 2. Declare an int variable called sum for the sum of the grades
       int sum;
      // 3. Declare a variable called average for the average of the grades
       int average;
      // 4. Write a formula to calculate the sum of the 3 grades (add them up).
       sum = grade1 + grade2 + grade3;
      // 5. Write a formula to calculate the average of the 3 grades from the sum using division and type casting.
       average = sum / 3;
      // 6. Print out the average
       System.out.println(average);
   }
}
```

This is my output (It wants a decimal but I don't know how to get it):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7pgh.png)

Comment: `double average = sum / 3.0;`: https://ideone.com/NViUIh

Comment: `sum / 3` is an integer operation. Make it double operation, a way is `sum / 3.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the average variable must be double
and you cast the division result to fit in the average variable

```
    double average;
    // 4. Write a formula to calculate the sum of the 3 grades (add them up).
    sum = grade1 + grade2 + grade3;
    // 5. Write a formula to calculate the average of the 3 grades from the sum using division and type casting.
    average = (double) sum / 3;
    System.out.println(average);
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply change the variable "average" to double.

```
double average=Double.valueOf(sum / 3);
```

Logic is:
At least one variable in the function (a/b) should be the type of double
Or we need to convert the int value to Double as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply divide by the double literal `3.0` or `3d` so that it performs floating point division instead of instead divison.

```
double average;
sum = grade1 + grade2 + grade3;
average = sum / 3.0;
```

[Demo!](https://ideone.com/NViUIh)

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the average to `double` to avoid any missing due to the cast from `double` to `int`

```
public class Challenge1_6 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int grade1 = 78;
       int grade2 = 95;
       int grade3 = 84;

       int sum;
       double average;
       sum = grade1 + grade2 + grade3;
       average = sum / 3;
       System.out.println(average);
   }
}
```